# MVC 4 - How do I turn off the default Error.vbhtml page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Anyone know how to turn off the default error page or where it's referenced??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.

Turns out that in my custom ElmahHandleErrorAttribute class, the OnException() method is indeed over ridden (as it should be). But the 1st line of code is "MyBase.OnException(context)", which will fire off what the HandleError attribute also performs.

Once I commented out that one line, my issue went away.

**What's The Issue?**

I have Elmah.Mvc implemented in this Mvc4 project, it's working beautifully. I also have a custom errors section in the Web.config as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/General">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Http404" />
</customErrors>
```

I have an ErrorController with two action methods, one for "General" and the other for "Http404".

What was happening was if I raised an unhandled error, I would indeed get my raised exception logged in Elmah, an email delivered with the exception, and then the custom "General" view displayed (Http404 page if it was a 404 error).

BUT, what I was also getting was an additional logged exception AND email because the default "Error.vbhtml" file was not found (I removed that view).

Honest mistake...hope this helps someone out moving along.  :)

Comment: Forgot to add that with this setup, you don't need to implement an Application_Error method in Global. If you are using compression, then you still need to, but the only line in it will be clearing the filters (prevents scrambled output when using compression).

Answer (score -1):

You can control this using the [customErrors element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28vs.71%29.aspx) in the web.config file.

Comment: I have that already set, but it seems on an unhandled error, somewhere in the MVC pipeline still wants to go to the default Error.vbhtml view (that I have deleted). SO that's not it.

Comment: I also have the "filters.Add(New HandleErrorAttribute)" line in the Global file commented out (I am using a custom ElmahHandleErrorAttribute instead).